# HTML, CSS, JS Как скрыть и показать элемент

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="darkmessage()">Growl</a>
...
<div class="darkmessage">
<div class="alert alert-warning section_right_alert" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
Test.
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.darkmessage {
display: none;
}
```

JS

```
function darkmessage() {
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('darkmessage');
if (b.style.display == 'block')
b.style.display = 'none';
else
b.style.display = 'block'
}
```

Как сделать при нажатии "Growl" сокрытие и раскрытие элемента с классом "darkmessage".

Comment: getElementsByClassName возвращает массив элементов. Обратите внимание - get elementS - множественное число. Сейчас актуальны функции querySelector и querySelectorAll которые возвращают соответственно первый и все найденные элементы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function darkmessage() {
  var b = document.querySelector('.darkmessage');
  if (b.style.display == 'block')
    b.style.display = 'none';
  else
    b.style.display = 'block'
}
```

```css
.darkmessage {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="darkmessage()">Growl</a> ...
<div class="darkmessage">
  <div class="alert alert-warning section_right_alert" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button> Test.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: b.style.display = b.style.display == 'block'? 'none' : 'block'

Comment: @axmed2004 - чудесно :)